# Unpacking error when testing method

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have this method:

```
def split_pointer_part(self, line):
    self.before_at, self.after_at = line.split('@', 1)
    return self.before_at, self.after_at
```

That is working, but when I run this test on it:

```
def test_split_pointer_part(self):
        line = '13797906 23 n 04 flood 0 inundation 0 deluge 0 torrent 0 005 @ 13796604 n 0000 + 00603894 a 0401 + 00753137 v 0302 + 01527311 v 0203 + 02361703 v 0101 | an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"'
        result = self.wn.split_pointer_part(line)
        answer = ('13797906 23 n 04 flood 0 inundation 0 deluge 0 torrent 0 005',' 13796604 n 0000 + 00603894 a 0401 + 00753137 v 0302 + 01527311 v 0203 + 02361703 v 0101 | an overwhelming number or amount; "a flood of requests"; "a torrent of abuse"')
        self.assertEqual(len(result), 2)
        for r, a in zip(result, answer):
            self.assertEqual(r, a)
```

this is the error I get:

```
self.before_at, self.after_at = line.split('@', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I know I should be using argv somewhere I just dont know how to use it in this scenario.

Comment: Are you sure that's the string you're trying to use - I'm surprised you're not getting an assertion error - I'm guessing that's not the actual data that's failing (and what I've based my answer on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there's nothing after the second split... Try using the following which will guarantee that `after_at` will be `''` if not present instead of raising an exception:

```
before_at, after_at = line.partition('@')[::2]
```